# Why can't I see source (with view source) when jquery loads external html into a div

Tags: jquery

Why can't I see source (with view source) when jquery loads external html into a div or when i bind data into div using jquery. I have need to view source code as it appears on front page for sitemap generator.

Comment: Use Chrome "Inspect" (on the context menu) instead of "view source" and you will be able to see the dynamic stuff, or just hit `ctrl`+`shift`+`I`

Comment: No My question is not that I can see the source when i inspect the element but I wanna when i simply view source on right click on the page

Comment: That's simply not what the "view source" option does, it only shows the *original* source of the page, not the current state after it has been modified via JS.

Answer (score -1):

The source code never changes. When you "view source" that shows you exactly what the browser received from the server.

This cannot be changed with JavaScript. The browser inspector shows a live representation of the DOM, so it will be updated by the JavaScript.

The only way to change the data when you click 'view source' is to send some data to the server, make the changes there, and then refresh the page by whatever method.

From `StackOverflow` post.

Comment: Nope, it only shows the original source code. Not the current state which could have been modified by Javascript.